# Kafka very large number of topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am considering Kafka to stream updates from the back-end to the front-end applications. 
- Data streams are specific to a user requests, so each request will generate a stream in the back-end. 
- Each user will have multiple concurrent requests. One to many relationship btw user and streams

I first thought I would setup a topic "per user request" but learnt that hundreds of thousands of topics is bad for multiple reasons.

Reading online, I came across posts that suggest one topic partitioned on userid. How is that any better than multiple topics?

If partitioning on userid is the way to go, the consumer will receive updates for different requests (from that user) and that will cause issues. I need to be able to not process a stream until I choose to, and if each request had it own topic this will work out great.

Thoughts?

Comment: Partition/topic is not to divide diffr set of data. May be you should reformat your question to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Kafka will be a good option for your use case. As your use case is somewhat "synchronous" and "dynamic" in nature. A user request is submitted and the client wait for the stream of response events, the client should also know when the response for a particular user request ends. Multiple user requests may end up in the same Kafka partition as we cannot afford to have an exclusive partition for each user when number of users is high.

I guess Redis may be a better use case for this use case. Every request can have an unique id, and response events are added to a Redis list with some reasonable expiry time. The Redis list is given the same key name as the request id.

Redis list will look like (key is request id):

request id -->  response even1, response event2,...... , response end evnt

The process which is relaying the event to the client will delete the list after it successfully sends all the response event to the client and the "last response event marker" is encountered.  If the relaying process dies before it can delete the response, Redis will take care of deleting the list after the list's expiry time.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible (I guess) to have a Kafka cluster of several thousends topics, I'm not sure it is the way to go in your particular case.

Usually you design your Kafka app around streams of data: like click-streams, page-views etc. Then, if you want some kind of "sticky" processors - you need partition key. In your case, if you select user id as a key, Kafka will store all events from an user to the same *partition*.

Kafka consumer, on the other side, read messages from 1 to all partitions of a topic. That means, if say, you have a topic with 10 partitions, you can start your Kafka consumer in a *consumer group* so every consumer has a distinct partitions assigned.

It means, for the user id example, all users will be processed by the exactly one consumer depending on the key. For example, userid A goes to partition 1, but userid B goes to partition 10.

Again, you can use message key in order to map your data stream to Kafka partitions. All events with the same key will be stored to the same partition and will be consumed/processed by the same consumer instance.